# Problems with spark session

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this error

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.$init$(org.apache.spark.internal.Logging)'
> at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.(SparkSession.scala:787)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.(SparkSession.scala)"

when i try to execute

```scala
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("MTBD")

val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("MTBD")
    .config(conf)
    .getOrCreate()"
```

if I comment out the `spark= SparkSession` and etc statement. There will be no error.

I'm using IntelliJ

other info:

```
scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.12

spark version 3.2.2


build.sbt 
"ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "provaMTBD"
  )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0")"
```

EDIT: In spark-shell I don't have errors and I can also read a csv.

this is the output of the spark-shell:

```
val  spark =  SparkSession.builder().appName("MTBD").config(conf).getOrCreate()
22/10/15 01:14:25 WARN SparkSession$Builder: Using an existing SparkSession; some spark core configurations may not take effect.
spark: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@5fbcc71d
```

Comment: You mention both Spark 3.2 but your build.sbt says Spark 2.1. Which one is it? It should be consistent.

Comment: I have installed version 3.2.2.
I modified the build.sbt file by inserting this line libraryDependencies ++ = Seq ("org.apache.spark"% "spark-core_2.11"% "2.1.0") "...after following a tutorial.
I also tried to change this line, editing the version, but I had new errors beyond this usual error.

Comment: The code itself looks good to me. Such errors are commonly caused by sub-module version incompatibility.  Check the build command is recommoned.

Answer (score 0):

I think the spark & scala versions are all mixed up.

if you are trying to us spark 3.2.2 then try using scala 2.12, like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.12" % "3.2.2"
```

ref: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.12/3.2.2/jar